# Where is my imported Windows account data?

Tags: windows-7, users, ubiquity, migration

I've just successfully installed my brand new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit, dual booting with Windows 7.

During the installation, I choose to import my existing Windows account but now I'm unable to find the account data (documents, images etc..) in my new Ubuntu.

Home, Documents, Images...folders seem to be empty..

Why that?

Thanks a lot,
Riccardo

Answer (score 1):

I think you're suffering from this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/migration-assistant/+bug/987902

They seem willing to fix it, but in a new upcoming "point" release of 12.04, 12.04.1.

I suggest that you [create a launchpad account](https://login.launchpad.net/+login) (or login) and click "This bug affects you and 1 other person" > "Yes it affects me" to increase the bug "heat" (its "importance").